# Azure Logic App - Google Drive Copy File - Connector is failing to upload file from Azure Fileshare

Tags: azure, google-drive-api, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am working on uploading a file to **Google drive** from **Azure Storage Account - File share** through **Azure Logic App** but hitting the "**Failed to fetch" error**.

Note:

- Google Authentication was successful after adding the connector inside logic app.
- Just getting the one line error message "Failed to fetch" and so it is challenging for us to troubleshoot as we are not sure what is causing the issue.

Could you please help us out here?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end this works fine after using the below flow in my logic apps.

[image]

**Logic app run**

[image]